# MailApp.sendEmail Problems with Breaks & Date format

Tags: javascript, email, datetime, google-apps-script

**I am trying to get 2 things corrected and I just cannot get to an answer. These are the 2:**

1. Include breaks where you see the commas within the `MailApp` statement.
2. `vA[i][3]` is a date. However, the format in the email is `yyyymmdd`. How do I change that to format `mm/dd/yy`?

**MailApp.sendEmail Statement**

`MailApp.sendEmail('xyz@gmail.com','iAlert!', 'Detected on: ' +vA[i][3]+' ,Type: '+vA[i][4]+' ,%Increase '+vA[i][5]+'.')`

Comment: You can use linebreaks through `"\n"`. Be aware that `\n` in single quotes is not interpreted the same way. You can format the date according to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: When I add "\n", so like this: 'Detected on: ' +vA[i][3]+ "\n"  ' ,Type: '+vA[i][4]+ "\n"  ' ,%Increase '+vA[i][5], it give me an error on the syntax. Can you assist please?

Comment: Try this: `'Detected on: ' +vA[i][3]+ "\n ,Type: "+vA[i][4]+ "\n ,%Increase "+vA[i][5]`. Double quotes are just as much a string as single quotes, but with double quotes you get some more options, such as linebreaks.